# More space between LabelText and HintText in TextFormField (Flutter)

Tags: flutter-layout

I want to increase the distance between labelText and hintText in a TextFormField, and contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(x, x, x, x), doesn't help me at all, it does apply a padding but those elements remain together.

My preview:[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with hintStyle and LabelStyle, set height attribute to what you want 
You can see my test result in picture 
code snippet

```
TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            hintText: 'What do people call you?',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(height:7, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            labelText: 'Name *',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(height:5, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                hintText: 'What do people call you?',
                hintStyle: TextStyle(height:7, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                labelText: 'Name *',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(height:5, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              onSaved: (String value) {
                // This optional block of code can be used to run
                // code when the user saves the form.
              },
              validator: (String value) {
                return value.contains('@') ? 'Do not use the @ char.' : null;
              },
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, it's ok-ish as a workaround for one single field but if you have more fields you will extend too much... unfortunately not fit my needs in that layout (maybe just a little bit with the height parameter on the hint text). Thanks for your effort!

Comment: This does not work when label text wraps horizontally

Answer (score 1):

I needed a TextField just with a label and no hint. My workaround to create space between was to provide the hint as an empty string. Hope this helps took me like 20 minutes to figure out

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintStyle: TextStyle(
      height: 3.0, // sets the distance between label and input
    ),
    hintText: '', // needed to create space between label and input
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      color: kWhiteTextColor,
      fontSize: 20.0,
    ),
    labelText: 'My first name is',
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextFormField(
            controller: controller.fullNameController,
            focusNode: controller.fullNameFocusNode,
            enabled: false,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                alignLabelWithHint: true,
                labelText: fullNameLabel,
                hintText: fullNameLabel,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  height: 0.5, // Tweak this 1,2 moves label bottom-> -1,-2 moves label upwards
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
                floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always),
          ),
```

Comment: I see quite alot of strange behaviour from this approach. The further negative you go, the greater the spacing, not just between the label and the field, but also between the lines of the label, also the label text lines flip around so line 2 is above line 1.

Answer (score 1):

I worked through all the other answers, and this is the only one that worked for me.

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 5),
    label: Container(
      transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -15.0, 0.0),
      child: const Text(
          'Label text here. This also allows you to have long lable text as you can use the space for 2 lines.'),
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are using a `OutlineInputBorder`, you can use `textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,` together with

```
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 28),
      border: OutlineInputBorder(
      )
    )
```

Adjust the contentPadding to your desired height.

Comment: When you use contentPadding you are overriding the default InputDecoration padding. Keep this in mind if you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!
Don't use labelText Parameter, instead, use the label parameter, wrap your text widget with padding widget then specify the amount of padding you want between label and text form field.
Like so
`label: Padding( padding: Const EdgeInsets.all(10), child:Text('your label text')`